# Would this 'collapsing' feature be useful on MSE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface

In the case where one wants to answer  a question using a number of propositions and lemmas with proofs, I think one can organize it better with [this feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability)  on Wikipedia for hiding proofs. The link shows how the proof of the integrability condition is hidden thus giving the section a sense of better **organization** with the *show*, *hide* buttons.

I think it will be a useful feature on MSE as one can

- Organize one's answer/question better.
- Make long responses appear shorter.

Other users may find other advantages of this feature but this is all I can think of.

Comment: cool idea ${ }$ ${ }$ ${ }$

Comment: I am adding link to the [current revision](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Riemann_integral&oldid=524667313#Integrability) of the Wikipedia article - just in case it changes in the future. BTW similar feature is available in many internet fora ([phpBB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phpbb)-based and similar).

Comment: I searched whether there were similar feature requests at meta.SO and I was able to find these:
[Long code in question: Adding a hide/display button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81318/long-code-in-question-adding-a-hide-display-button)
and
[Toggle / collapse images and other parts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93865/toggle-collapse-images-and-other-parts).

Comment: It was just pointed out to me that I started the same discussion on Physics: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2754/adding-collapsable-fields-to-answers